# Navbar sprite window size issue

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

[My JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/AATSC/)
So I'm having an issue. This is my first website ever and I'm trying to put my navbar/header at the top of the website. The issue here is it only shows depending on the size of the window. I tried using

```
background-size: cover;
```

but when the window is full size you see the image under the primary for link hover.
Any help would be much appreciated as to what I can do! Thanks :)

Comment: I implore you to rethink this approach. These are very old techniques and I suggest you start on the right foot. I can't see any images in your fiddle so it's hard to tell what is going on. the use of tons of absolute *magic* numbers like, 107px is really scary. Let me help you. Make a jsfiddle that works.

Comment: Ok ill make a jsfiddle that works let me try. I'm very new to web dev and i never know if im doing the right or wrong thing. i realize that my magic numbers are scary but im not sure what to do about that. Give me a bit and ill update this with a new working js fiddle

Comment: http://mikak.site88.net/ is the main site that i use for testing. Everything works in dreamweaver but for some reason it shows up all wack on the sight
http://jsfiddle.net/AATSC/2/ 
here is the fiddle unfortunatly i still have a tun of magic numbers also the js fiddle does work its just [portfolio, other, about] thoes 3 the image linking isnt right. also for some reason the <span> isnt hidden like i set. There are images for sure if you cant see them try resizing the output box to the entire screen and you might be able to see something.

Comment: I can't bear to help you with the image problem. But there is another problem that I can help you with.

The answer is: Stop using dream weaver. Rethink everything. Learn HTML and CSS. Start with THIS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/XJtCn/ Then get sublime text and make your website. I don't say this to be dogmatic or a jerk, but I can tell that you actually want to learn and I offer this path as a person who was once in your shoes. I wasted years fuddling around with dreamweaver and when I finally decided to start from the beginning and learn everything, it only took me a few months.

Comment: Good luck! You can do it!

Comment: *There isn't a single px in the whole fiddle I just made for you.*

Comment: oh man thankyou that fiddle was amainzg

Comment: Thankyou so much i really apreciate your help i do really want to learn this. Where do you think i would start learning then if i throw out dreamweaver. The website you made there was amazing and ill keep it in referance as to learn from it. Thank you.

Comment: I guess I watched a video series on Lynda.com - the one Lynda's brother did. But right after that, I learned that it was all outdated. Then I just Googled things and read stuff by Chris Coyier on CSS-tricks and all of the "future friendly" people and stuff. http://htmlandcssbook.com/ This book is pretty good. When I saw it, I wish I had it when I started. It's important to understand the box-model early on. Position relative, and position absolute, and floats. It's just a lot of making little practice websites. Don't get to precious about anything yet. Just do little tests and it will happen.

Comment: Thankyou yeah i was having a hard time with the position relative and absolute i didnt quite get what they did i mostly just tried changing them multiple times to see what they did and how i could use them. Dreamweaver introduced a whole lot of functions through suggestion that i didnt quite understand. But anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: They didn't name them very well if you ask me... *relative* should be called "parent" or something and *absolute* should be called relative or "child." - Things that are position: absolute; are positioned ""relatively"" to their nearest parent (the closest thing with position: relative;) ---- CONFUSING ! Then there is block and inline and inline block - and then there's the micro clear fix... that's basically all the major pitfalls.

Comment: so then what would the point of making a position relative just to set a base point? also what would be fixed just a point that will sit on yoru screen no matter the scroll? and how does that function while using other positions does it cout as ontop? So many questions

Comment: fixed is "fixed and doesn't move - but the order of the html, by default, sets the layering top to bottom... so if you had three divs, and they were all fixed, the lower in the DOM it is (look up dom) the higher it is... in which case you use z-index. look that up too. I use absolute positioning once or twice per webpage - and fixed... maybe once for a header maybe when the screen gets big and has enough room to dedicate to a fixed header. People, until recently made whole sites, like your example, with all absolute. The problem with absolute, is that it is "absolute."

Comment: Quick question on your site theres a little ☯(ying-yang) where is that i wanted to see how you put it there so i could learn how to do that but i cant even see the symbol in your code

Comment: http://craigslistadtracker.com/fancy-ad-titles.aspx You can find HTML symbols on sites like this. - for the most part I use icon fonts, but these are quick for placement and icon fonts require quite a bit more knowledge of adding scripts and using proper technique. I suggest you keep it simple for a while.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to use a sprite for my logo in particular once i get a better grasp of html/css?

Comment: It would be worthwhile to get a codepen.io account and do some practice with sprites, for sure. - but to be foreward thinking... your compass logo, as I remember it, should probably be an svg in the future... iphone 5s is coming out with a crazy dense resolution, and currently, sprites can't deal with the resolution issues we are dealing with. you would have to have php server-side - or picturefill.js dealing with the image switching. The key is not to think about what you want... it's to think about what you CAN do and be punk rock about it, and within those constraints - make the best things

Comment: I rad across this article. It was written in 2011 but is pretty solid and concise - http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/ I think you will find it useful.

Comment: Sounds awsome thanks for the info sorry im a bit slow at responding i just put together my new computer so now i can really start with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but if you want your image to not extent outside its container, use

```
background-position: 0px -50px; /* approx 50px */
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Thanks for this once unfortunatly i need the top image first :)

Comment: i created the sprite myself so i cant really just change the image thers only one image